# using SSH to log into a non-root account using root password

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am trying to log into a server with a particular account. Let's say I don't know the password for that account. Can I do this using ssh? I am wondering if it is possible to do it in one command, instead of logging in as root and running su.

Comment: Hmmm... this may be a bad question, but thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be

```
ssh root@host su - user
```

Comment: you'd have to make sure sshd.conf isn't set to squash root logins.  You really don't want to do this (unless you're using key based auth, or some physical token, even then it's too risky)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make sense.  If you're logged in as root, a plain `su` doesn't do anything except start a new shell.  Maybe you mean `su someotheruser`?

As far as I know, most Linux installations don't allow root logging in remotely directly.  One first has to log in as an ordinary user and su to become root.

Comment: eh, plenty of systems allow root logins

Comment: He means using `su [-] user` form of `su` to become another user.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably accomplish this if you were willing to write a [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules) module which caused entering the root password to make authentication succeed.  Not going to be easy, but it would do what you want...

Answer (score 1):

No ...............